Serialize specific build targets during build process
I am facing fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space issue on Windows OS while compiling specific .c files in my project. Those .c files are huge and they eat memory when i run the build in -j%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% which will consume all available cpu cores (i.e 20) and results to memory issues. I try to reduce no of cores to -j10, But still i face heap space issues intermittently.
I want to serialize those specific .c files and came across .NOTPARALLEL in Make . I try to tag those problematic .obj (eg: foo.obj, bar.obj....like there are 15 such .obj) files compilation with .NOTPARALLEL, But build time is increased with that, Reason is because pre-req of foo.obj ,bar.obj files are also running in serial mode i guess right?
how can i work around this? is there a way to just limit the serialization only for problematic .obj files but not its pre-requisites ?

The first thing to check is that you're using GNU Make 4.4 or above.  The capability for individual targets to be marked as not parallel was introduced in that release.  Before that adding .NOTPARALLEL: to your makefile forced all targets to be run serially and disabled parallelism completely (regardless of prerequisites).

lets say if we have targets a,b,c,d and there is no dependency among them. if i set NOTPATALLEL to c and d, How come that disable parallelism completely? I can still expect a,b to run in parallel right?

The make version i am using is > 4.4 , Is there any Work around to handle my case?

Prior to GNU Make 4.4, there was no way to specify parallelism on a per-target basis.  You could only enable it for the entire instance of make, or disable it.  Starting in 4.4 you can specify parallelism for specific targets.

I don't know what prerequisites of these .obj files there could be: typically the only prerequisites of an object file are source files and header files, which don't need to be built and so there are no recipes to build them that could run serially.
Nevertheless your supposition is incorrect: the .NOTPARALLEL option applies only to the specific targets you list, not to any other targets (including the prerequisites of those targets).
In other words, this makefile:
all: foo.x foo.y

.NOTPARALLEL: foo

Is identical to writing this makefile:
all: foo.x .WAIT foo.y

(you can read about .WAIT here but it works more or less as you'd expect.)
Adding .obj files to .NOTPARALLEL generally doesn't do what you want.  There is no way in GNU Make (or any make that I'm aware of) to list a target, like foo.obj, and say this particular target should always be built serially.  That turns out to be hard to do, so make does something different: it allows you to specify that all prerequisites of a given target should be built serially.
Just FYI, here's an example makefile that shows your guess is not correct:
all: foo.x .WAIT foo.y

foo.x foo.y: foo.z bar.z

foo.x foo.y foo.z bar.z: ; @echo start $@; sleep 2; echo stop $@

.NOTPARALLEL: all

When you run make with this makefile you'll see:
start foo.z
start bar.z
  ...wait 2 seconds...
stop foo.z
stop bar.z
start foo.x
  ...wait 2 seconds...
stop foo.x
start foo.y
  ...wait 2 seconds...
stop foo.y

As you can see, by declaring all to be .NOTPARALLEL all its prerequisites (foo.x and foo.y) are built serially, but the prerequisites of those targets (foo.z and bar.z) are still built in parallel.
In order for us to help you more you'll need to provide us with a minimal reproducible example of what you're trying to do and show the problem you're seeing.
